# Authorized SSL for Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate

I moved my stack(nodejs based restapi, UI/UX asp.net mvc by another team) to production mode on AWS.

I have an issue with ssl certificate.

The ssl certificate i use on nodejs is self signed as a result i get "certificate not trusted" issue on the browser while trying to access the client.

When i was looking for IP based CA certificates, i realized it can be issued only for organization based IPs.

Since i am hosting the nodejs server on ec2 this ip doesnt belong to my organization. Please let me know what is the best way out of this

Comment: Do you expressly need an IP based cert? If so why

Comment: Need not be an IP based cert. But is there any other way i can tackle this?